# JWT verify Fastify

Tags: node.js, jwt, fastify

using fastify
i am trying to add 2 types of JWT auth
by using this code

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin';
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify';
import '@fastify/jwt';

declare module '@fastify/jwt' {
    interface FastifyJWT {
        payload: { id: number };
        user: {
            id: number;
            fullName: string;
            email: number;
            phoneNumber: number;
            role: string;
            blocked: false;
            userMethod: string;
            verified: boolean;
            createdAt: string;
        };
    }
}

const jwtPlugin = async (instance: FastifyInstance) => {
    instance.register(import('@fastify/jwt'), {
        secret: instance.configs.jwt.secret,
    });

    instance.decorate('authenticate', async (request: FastifyRequest) => {
        try {
            await request.jwtVerify();
        } catch (error) {
            throw instance.httpErrors.unauthorized();
        }
    });
    // check if user is authenticated without throwing error (used for check user location)
    instance.decorate('isAuthenticated', async (request: FastifyRequest) => {
        try {
            await request.jwtVerify();
        } catch (error) {
            return;
        }
    });
};

export default fp(jwtPlugin, {
    name: 'jwt-plugin',
});
```

i am getting this erro on the async func

in the `instance.decorate`

here
`async (request: FastifyRequest) => {`

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(property: string | symbol, value: null): FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(request: FastifyRequest) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(property: "isAuthenticated", value: GetterSetter<FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>, (this: FastifyInstance<...>) => void>, dependencies?: string[] | undefined): FastifyInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(request: FastifyRequest) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetterSetter<FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>, (this: FastifyInstance<...>) => void>'.
      Type '(request: FastifyRequest) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(this: FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>) => void'.
        Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.ts(2769)
```

how can i fix that ?
i did copy the code from another project that i worked on
and it is the same code and it was working fine there

Comment: Please, provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it's not clear what line is producing the error and what imports are used.

Comment: @OSA413 i did edit the entire post ,, added all the file and where is the error

Comment: The code doesn't throw this error in my case. Please, provide versions of the packages used.

Comment: @OSA413 "@fastify/jwt": "^7.2.4","fastify": "^4.24.3"